# what the woman is saying in this conversation?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> man: No, because it's really expensive to hire somebody in Canada to
> come and clean  your house. And really people just take the chores on
> for themselves because it's hard to  afford to get somebody to, to
> come in and wash your, wash your laundry and wash the,  the windows
> and all that kind of stuff. So.
>
> woman: It's something that's really out of the question. It's out of
> our budget. I mean, **I think you're paying somebody 30 dollars an
> hour. Usually, it's a cleaning company, though**, so they have some
> usually a woman that  is coming and she does the cleaning and the
> company is taking their cut. (they're man and wife)

I don't know exactly what the woman want to say. Especially, why she said like the sentence in bold?

He certainly said it was hard to get somebody handle chores and that kind of things. i feel like her answer doesn't match the context.

Comment: Sometimes people use the present continuous to describe a hypothetical situation (this is not formal usage - it's very colloquial).  So this can be read to mean, "I think you would have to pay somebody 30 dollars an hour."

Answer (score 4):

It is typical of the rambling, somewhat inconsequential way many people speak. She starts

> It’s out of the question

She then realizes that she has given no reason for that assertion (although her husband had). So she clarifies with

> It’s outside our budget.

She then realizes that her clarification is very unspecific. Would it be outside her budget if it cost 2 dollars a day?

> [The reason it’s outside our budget is the price:] you’re paying someone 30 dollars an hour.

Now she realizes that she is complaining that someone is making a decent wage so she backtracks and says that some company is charging a high price while perhaps not providing a decent wage.

> [Actually, I personally do not begrudge the money paid to the cleaning woman because you are not paying her at all but rather] you are paying an [impersonal] company and they are taking their cut [which for all I know may be huge].

You can follow the way her mind works once you realize that what she says is only half of what drifts through her mind. She could have said

> My husband’s right that it is too expensive: it costs 30 dollars an hour